# Problem with LINQ to Entities and String.StartsWith

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to build a search page using LINQ to Entities, but the following code is giving me a runtime error about l.t.e. not recognising 'Boolean StartsWith().  The code compiles just fine.  How can I work around this better than shipping the StartsWith filtering out to a stored proc?

```
    return from dp in dents.DirectoryPersonEntrySet
           where
               ((dp.LastName.StartsWith(searchTerm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) ||
                (dp.Department.StartsWith(searchTerm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) ||
                dp.Extension.StartsWith(searchTerm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
           select dp;
```

Comment: Could you post the 'following code'? Or is the subject the complete code? You mean String.StartsWith instead of Boolean.StartsWith?

Comment: @Rutger, thanks, I was too quick to hit send and forgot the code.  I also fixed the signature.

Comment: There're at least 6 parentheses in excess, and we're still missing the function prototype and the class definition...

Comment: Try using StartsWith overload without StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.

Comment: I have not used LINQ to Entities so I don't know whether it supports wildcards, but can't you use "like" plus a wild card?

Comment: @emaster:  What function prototype or class definition would you like?  Everything relevant to my question is present, and the surplus parentheses have no bearing on the issue.

Comment: Related posts - [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7259567/465053) & [Entity Framework Specification Pattern Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352764/465053)

Comment: Another related post - [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5899683/465053)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I would guess that EF doesn't support the overload of StartsWith that takes a StringComparison parameter.

It should support **StartsWith**, **EndsWith** and **Contains**, so maybe you can try:

```
dp.LastName.StartsWith(searchTerm)
```

or:

```
dp.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith(searchTerm)
```

and then make sure that `searchTerm` is also lowercase.

Comment: Guessed correctly, but mind that it is case insensitive when translated to SQL.

Comment: MAY be (is probably) case insensitive.  It depends on the database collation settings

Comment: It translates it to a LIKE statement with 'my string%', '%my string' and '%my string%' respectively, which is case-insensitive automatically and no way to specify it to be case-sensitive via this call

Comment: life saver. I spent an hour to investigate it and didn't notice that I have used the overload method. +1

Comment: If you are using SQLite these three methods dont work everytime as expected...

Comment: That solution did not work for me in .Net 4.7.2. I think it's a bug.