# Entity math does not recognize the method 'Double Acos(Double)'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, floating-point

I have this entity code that is giving me issues, it doens't give an error until I load the page and then the error says. 
**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Acos(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression**
I am doing the haversine function to get the radius of a point, I know that Math returns a **Double** thats why I have cast it and I have to use floats as thats the only format the CSV files are in, how can i correct the above error?

```
 var ste = (from s in db.zipss where Math.Acos(Math.Sin(28.46348)
 * Math.Sin((float)s.latitude) + Math.Cos(28.46348) * Math.Cos((float)s.longitude - 
(-81.3881))) * 3960 <= 5 select s.zipcode).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: create a variable, set the value to your math, and then use the variable instead. [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259567/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method)

Answer (score 0):

The expression can't be translated, for LINQ to Entities. Since no other solutions have been proposed, I guess you can always do the query in memory, i.e. go to LINQ to Objects, as in:

```
var ste = (from s in db.zipss.AsEnumerable()  // note AsEnumerable
           where Math.Acos(Math.Sin(28.46348) * Math.Sin((float)s.latitude)
               + Math.Cos(28.46348) * Math.Cos((float)s.longitude - (-81.3881)))
               * 3960 <= 5
           select s.zipcode).FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't know if this will be too slow to be practical. I don't know about the casts to `float`. Maybe you can omit them (if `.latitude` and `.longitude` are already `float`, a `float` can implicitly promote to a `double`).