# Issue with Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Struggling Newbie :(

Entity not fetching the User..

Login Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginForm(string user_NA, string user_pwd)
{
    User u = new User();
    u.LogIn(user_NA, user_pwd);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Login Model

```
public bool LogIn(string userID, string password)
{
    using (Entity.xcLEntities en = new xcLEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            var user = en.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.LoginID == userID && x.PasswordHash == this.SetPassword(password));
            if (user != null && password != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

    }
}
```

Exception shoing

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in AML.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String SetPassword(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

Comment: How should I fetch the User using ID ?

Comment: Are you sure the user is there? If you get all the users, do you see the user with the `LoginID` you're testing?

Comment: @AndreiV Did u mean the entity one?

Comment: I can create Users in the same application without issues .

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your exception, you could try getting the corresponding hash outside the `SingleOrDefault` method:

```
public bool LogIn(string userID, string password)
{
    using (Entity.AMLEntities en = new AMLEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            string hashed = this.SetPassword(password);
            var user = en.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.LoginID == userID && x.PasswordHash == hashed);
            if (user != null && password != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**: As suggested by Rezoan in the comments, more information can be found by reading [Entity Framework can't run your C# code as part of its query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259567/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method).

Comment: Thanks... It would be very grateful if u let me know why it's not accepted in my code :)

Comment: I'm no expert in lambda expressions but it might have something to do with the fact that inside your lambda expression, there's another "instance", i.e. the keyword `this` is not referring your `User` instance. Maybe someone can provide a better explanation.

Comment: @JRU Entity Framework can't actually run your C# code as part of its query. see the answer of StriplingWarrior on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259567/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method

Answer (score 0):

You should store the result of the SetPassword methon in a local varoable and use the varoable in the lambda expression. The exception is clearly state that the setpassword method is not avaliable on the db side.