# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

This is my Code where I am fetching data.

```
var list = (from u in _dbContext.Users
                        where u.IsActive
                              && u.IsVisible
                              && u.IsPuller.HasValue
                              && u.IsPuller.Value
                        select new PartsPullerUsers
                               {
                                   AvatarCroppedAbsolutePath = u.AvatarCroppedAbsolutePath,
                                   Bio = u.Bio,
                                   CreateDateTime = u.CreationDate,
                                   Id = u.Id,
                                   ModifieDateTime = u.LastModificationDate,
                                   ReviewCount = u.ReviewsReceived.Count(review => review.IsActive && review.IsVisible),
                                   UserName = u.UserName,
                                   Locations = (from ul in _dbContext.UserLocationRelationships
                                                join l in _dbContext.Locations on ul.LocationId equals l.Id
                                                where ul.IsActive && ul.UserId == u.Id
                                                select new PartsPullerLocation
                                                       {
                                                           LocationId = ul.LocationId,
                                                           Name = ul.Location.Name
                                                       }),
                                   Rating = u.GetPullerRating()
                               });
```

Now Here is my Extension.

```
public static int GetPullerRating(this User source)
        {
            var reviewCount = source.ReviewsReceived.Count(r => r.IsActive && r.IsVisible);
            if (reviewCount == 0)
                return 0;

            var totalSum = source.ReviewsReceived.Where(r => r.IsActive && r.IsVisible).Sum(r => r.Rating);
            var averageRating = totalSum / reviewCount;

            return averageRating;
        }
```

I have check this Post [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259567/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method)

And I come to know I need to use

```
public System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Row52.Data.Entities.User, int>> GetPullerRatingtest
```

But how ? 
Thanks

Comment: you just need to call `ToList()` to load your items from the database before doing complex calculations to create the object

Comment: @Jonesy Thanks Let me do this.

Comment: Unrelated.. but to be honest I think you should refactor this code into a loop.

Comment: is the extension method in the same file?  are you missing a reference?

Comment: @user3444160 Extension file is diff and I already add ref for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use conditionals inside LINQ to Entity queries:

```
AverageRating = u.ReviewsReceived.Count(r => r.IsActive && r.IsVisible) > 0 ? 
                u.ReviewsReceived.Where(r => r.IsActive && r.IsVisible).Sum(r => r.Rating) / 
                u.ReviewsReceived.Count(r => r.IsActive && r.IsVisible)
                : 0
```

This will be calculated by the server, and returned as part of your list. Although with 10 million rows like you said, I would do some serious filtering before executing this.

Comment: Thanks It's exactly what I want . :)

Answer (score 1):

Code within LINQ (to Entities) query is executed within database, so you can't put random C# code there.  So you should either use `user.GetPullerRating()` after it is retrieved or create a property if you don't want to do the calculation every time.

You can also do:

```
foreach (var u in list)
   u.Rating = u.GetPullerRating()
```

By the way, why is it extension method.

Comment: How does the compiler validate whether an extension method can be bound to a type? Is there a flag/attribute on the entities class?

Comment: @LewsTherin as I understand there is currently no mechanism to create custom extension methods, because they are hardcoded in Linq implementation (to EF). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx

Comment: @Andrey Sorry can not Use Foreach loop because there 10 million records.

Comment: @ujjaval you do query 10 mil records and you can't foreach them? Honestly I have a feeling that you are trying to approach the problem in a wrong way. Why would you need so many rows from your DB into your app?