# Search query database first mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I would like to create a search button which would enable a user to search for a member and load associated details. I am using also Ajax BeginForm.

There are 3 classes/tables:

```
    public Book()
    {
        this.Loans = new HashSet<Loan>();
    }

    public int ISBN { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public int OnLoan { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Loan> Loans { get; set; }
}
   Loan Class
  public partial class Loan
{
    public int LoanId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CheckOutDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
    public decimal FinePrice { get; set; }
     public Nullable<int> MemberId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ISBN { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public virtual Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

Member Class:

```
  public partial class Member
    {
        public Member()
        {
            this.Loans = new HashSet<Loan>();
        }

        public int MemberId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public int TelNo { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Loan> Loans { get; set; }
    }
```

In my BHistory Controller:

```
public ActionResult HistorySearch(string qh)
{
    var history = Gethistory(qh);

    return PartialView(history);


}
private List<Loan> Gethistory(string searchString)
{
    return db.Loans
        .Where(a => a.MemberId.ToString().Contains(searchString) && a.Book.OnLoan == 1)
       .ToList();
}
```

So at the moment the search works fine, it returns the correct result, in the browser the user enters memberid and **a list of results appear. However I only want the last of the results to appear. Not a list of results**

so instead of using ToList(), I want to use LastorDefault(),
but I get the error message:
 cannot convert Models.Loan to collections.generic.list.

So I edited the ActionMethod

```
private Loan Gethistory(string searchString)
    {
        return db.Loans
            .Where(a => a.MemberId.ToString().Contains(searchString) && a.Book.OnLoan == 1)
           .LastorDefault();
```

However when I run this I get the error message:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Library1.Models.Loan LastOrDefaultLoan' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

In conclusion how do I get the last of the results to appear, not a list.

This question is different from questions that refer to answers with the use of Last() or LastorDefault() because here even if we switch to using OrderByDescending() and First() or FirstorDefault() the answer/result would not work. 
The error also lied in the ability of returning a list even when I thought the answer should not return a list

Thanks

Comment: Also please include the source code for the partial view `HistorySearch`.

Comment: You should also add an ORDER BY to ensure you get the row you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the model on your page is looking for a `List<Loan>`, and you're only sending it a `Loan`. As of the time that I posted this answer, you don't have your controller method or view as part of your question, so I would change your query to this:

```
private List<Loan> Gethistory(string searchString)
{
    var loan = db.Loans
                 .Where(a => a.MemberId
                              .ToString()
                              .Contains(searchString) && 
                             a.Book.OnLoan == 1)
                 .OrderByDescending(a => a.LoanId)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

    return new List<Loan> { loan };
}
```

As Stefan said in his answer, SQL doesn't have a `LastOrDefault` method, so you need to write your query in a way that is easier for EF to convert to SQL.

Alternatively, you could change your View to have a model that is a single Loan, though that would make the (presumable) grid you're displaying them/it in a little less intuitive.

Comment: Thanks I will have a go at this. Appreciate your help

Comment: You're welcome. The error message you shared about not being able to convert a `Loan` to `List<Loan>` is how I was able to deduce this was your issue. The error is being thrown as the Razor engine is trying to generate your page.

Comment: if the user types in an incorrect MemberId then I would want an error message to appear as appose to dbnullexception appearing. How would I implement that? really appreciate this.

Comment: If you're doing a single Member or Loan, you don't want to return the same View. You should have multiple views. The view for a single Loan would be more of a details page than a grid showing multiple Loans.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 return db.Loans
        .Where(a => a.MemberId.ToString().Contains(searchString) && a.Book.OnLoan == 1)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.MemberId)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

SQL does not understand `LastOrDefault`

So, you'll need to order the list. By using `OrderByDescending` you will invert this order and, hence, can take the top record.

If you still want to pass in a collection, you can also use the `OrderByDescending`

```
return db.Loans
        .Where(a => a.MemberId.ToString().Contains(searchString) && a.Book.OnLoan == 1)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.MemberId);
```

See [LINQ To Entities does not recognize the method Last. Really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293639/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-last-really) for more details.

Or this similar question:

[remove a record with child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650935/remove-a-record-with-child/44651025#44651025)

Comment: Thanks I will check out the links. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Use .LastOrDefault(...) instead of .where

return db.Loans
            .**LastOrDefault**(a => a.MemberId.ToString().Contains(searchString) && a.Book.OnLoan == 1);

It also improves your performance.