# How can i fix "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method" error

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, enums

I got LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetName(System.Type, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How can i fix that? I did not find a suitable example for my case.

```
 return context.Books.Select(e => new BookViewModel
            {
                BookId = e.BookId,
                BookName = e.BookName,
                Genre = new GenreViewModel
                { GenreName = Enum.GetName(typeof(Genre), (int)e.Genre), GenreId = (int)e.Genre },// error is here
                Pages = e.Pages,
                Publisher = e.Publisher,
                Authors = e.Authors.Select(t => new AuthorViewModel
                {
                    AuthorId = t.AuthorId,
                    AuthorName = t.AuthorName
                }).ToList()
            });
```

Models:

```
public enum Genre
{
[Description("Comedy")]
Comedy,
[Description("Drama")]
Drama,
[Description("Horror")]
Horror,
[Description("Realism")]
Realism,
[Description("Romance")]
Romance,
[Description("Satire")]
Satire,
[Description("Tragedy")]
Tragedy,
[Description("Tragicomedy")]
Tragicomedy,
[Description("Fantasy")]
Fantasy,
[Description("Mythology")]
Mythology,
[Description("Adventure")]
Adventure,
}
public class GenreViewModel
{
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string GenreName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259567/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method)

Comment: Depending on your EF version you can probably just do `e.Genre.ToString()`.

Comment: I will check it now, version: EntityFramework.6.1.3

Comment: So just use `ToString()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use a simple getter for GenreName in your ViewModel

```
public class GenreViewModel
{
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string GenreName { get{ return Enum.GetName(typeof(Genre), GenreId);}}
}
```

So you don't need to put this in the `Select` clause.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is really a very simple and effective solution)