# How to call Calculate Age and call method in Linq , windows form

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get this error message when I load all employees when I load employees in dataGridView  form.

> "LINQ to Entities Does Not Recognize the Method 'int32 CalculateAge(Int32)'  method, and this methode cannot be translate into a store expression"

This is how I populate them in dataGridView

```c#
private void LoaddEmployees() {
   try
    {
        db = new EmployeeEntities();

        var employees = (from u in db.Users 
                         select new
                         {
                             EmployeeId = u.EmployeeId,
                             UserName = u.UserName,
                             FirstName = u.FirstName,
                             LastName = u.LastName,
                             Birthday = u.Birthday,
                             Age = CalculateAge(u.EmployeeId) // Calling CalculateAge method
                         }).ToList();
        dgvEmployeesList.DataSource = employees;                  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And here is my CalculateAge Method that I have problem with. The very calculation (Mathematics) is working but get error when I load my dataGridview.

```c#
 private int CalculateAge(int employeeId) {

    int age;
    var employeeAge = db.Users.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeId).FirstOrDefault();

            DateTime empBirthday = Convert.ToDateTime(empAge.Birthday);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            age = today.Year - empBirthday.Year;
            if (empBirthday > today.AddYears(-age)) 
                age--;
                return age; 
}
```

When page loading then I get the above error:

Please I need your help to solve this problem. I really do not understand what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259567/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert db.Users to list and then run evaluate your age calculation. The code would look something like

```
private void LoaddEmployees()
    {
        try
        {
            db = new EmployeeEntities();

            var employees = (from u in db.Users.ToList()
                             select new
                             {
                                 EmployeeId = u.EmployeeId,
                                 UserName = u.UserName,
                                 FirstName = u.FirstName,
                                 LastName = u.LastName,
                                 Birthday = u.Birthday,
                                 Age = CalculateAge(u.Birthday) // note that we are sending in the Birthday
                             }).ToList();
            dgvEmployeesList.DataSource = employees;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And then update the CalculateAge method as

```
private int CalculateAge(string birthday)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(birthday)) return 0;

        DateTime empBirthday = Convert.ToDateTime(birthday);
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        age = today.Year - empBirthday.Year;
        if (empBirthday > today.AddYears(-age))
            age--;
        return age;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Working perfekt !

Answer (score 0):

```
 var employees = (from u in db.Users 
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     EmployeeId = u.EmployeeId,
                                     UserName = u.UserName,
                                     FirstName = u.FirstName,
                                     LastName = u.LastName,
                                     Birthday = u.Birthday,
                                     Age = CalculateAge(u.EmployeeId) // Calling CalculateAge method
                                 })
```

This part of your code is converted into SQL query by Entity Framework and sadly your C# method `CalculateAge(u.EmployeeId)` can't be converted to SQL. You can't use that kind of custom methods with `IQueryable`. First retrieve data then apply method or do same calculation on SQL side (for example stored procedure).