# C# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean'

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have the following linq expression in lambda syntax:

```
var myValue = 6;
var from = 2;
var to = 8;

var res = MyList.Where(m => m.person.Id == person.Id
                         && IsBetween(myValue, from, to))
                .Select(x => new Person { blah blah blah })
                .ToList());
```

IsBetween is simple generic helper method to see whether I have something in between:

```
public bool IsBetween<T>(T element, T start, T end)
{
    return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(element, start) >= 0
        && Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(element, end) <= 0;
}
```

Now I get this error, and I don't know hot to get around it:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsBetween[Decimal](System.Decimal, System.Decimal, System.Decimal)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: How would that be useful anyway, given that `myValue`, `from` and `to` are all hard-coded, and not part of your entity? Please give a more realistic example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [all of these](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=C%23+LINQ+to+Entities+does+not+recognize+the+method).

Comment: Those values are just hardcoded for the example. The values are passed as arguments on my method signature.

Comment: It is really interesting...prior to writing my question I was searching for similar questions. Now I may be very wrong, but the other questions were built-in calls like tostring() etc. I was wondering whether a custom method like IsBetween was different since it is custom made by me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method)

Comment: Take a look at this approach as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342632/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-boolean-containsany/47342694#47342694

Comment: Related posts - [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7259567/465053) & [Entity Framework Specification Pattern Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352764/465053)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot call arbitrary methods from within a LINQ to Entities query, as the query is executed within the SQL database engine.  You can only call methods which the framework can translate into equivalent SQL.

If you need to call an arbitrary method, the query operator calling the method call will need to be preceded by an `AsEnumerable()` operator such that the call happens client-side.  Be aware that by doing this, all results to the left-hand side of `AsEnumerable()` will potentially be loaded into memory and processed.

In cases where the method you are calling is short enough, I would simply inline the logic.  In your case, you would also need to drop the `Comparer` calls, and `IsBetween(myValue, from, to)` would simply become `myValue >= from && myValue <= to`.

Comment: using `AsEnumerable` is the solution we found in many other references and it is a short but not efficient solution when all the data is pulled from the server to the client. I would like to see some solution using Expression tree here.

Comment: I found that searching on other sites as well. I may have to rewrite my expression then. :(

Comment: Your method is short enough that you could inline the logic.  I would just do that.  However, you'll have to replace the comparer calls with equivalent relational operators (`<`, `>`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to this, if you want to pass the values to IsBetween method from MyList.

Take a wrapper class (here Person) contains the same properties to be passed to the method. 
    and do something like this:

```
var res = MyList.Where(m => m.person.Id == person.Id)
            .Select(x => new Person { p1 = x.p1, p2 = x.p2 })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .where(x => (IsBetween(x.p1, x.p2)))
            .ToList());
```