# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Boolean ContainsAny

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

**Error**

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   ContainsAny(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

**Code**

```
var predicate = FilterClients(clientRequest);
clients = db.Clients.Where(predicate).Include(x => x.Organization) 
.Include(x => x.Department).ToList();

private Expression<Func<Client, bool>> FilterClients(ClientRequest clientRequest)
{
   var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Client>();

   if (clientRequest.IsBySearchPatternFullName)
   {
      var searchPatternFullName = clientRequest.SearchPatternFullName.Trim();
      var matches = Regex.Matches(searchPatternFullName, @"\w+[^\s]*\w+|\w");
      var words = new List<string>();
      foreach (Match match in matches)
      {
         var word = match.Value;
         words.Add(word);
      }
      var wordArray = words.ToArray();
      predicate = predicate.And(x => x.LastName.ContainsAny(wordArray) || x.FirstName.ContainsAny(wordArray) || x.MiddleName.ContainsAny(wordArray));
   }
   return predicate;
}
```

There is similar question [C# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022250/c-sharp-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-boolean)

But I would like to optimize this part somehow

```
 predicate = predicate.And(x => x.LastName.ContainsAny(wordArray) || x.FirstName.ContainsAny(wordArray) || x.MiddleName.ContainsAny(wordArray));
```

Any clue people?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022250/c-sharp-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-boolean)

Comment: Related posts - [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7259567/465053) & [Entity Framework Specification Pattern Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352764/465053)

Comment: Another related post - [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5899683/465053)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I just did it!

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
   var word = match.Value;                   
   predicate = predicate.And(x => x.LastName.Contains(word) || x.FirstName.Contains(word) || x.MiddleName.Contains(word));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query against list of word in following way :

```
 predicate = predicate.And(x => wordArray.Contains(x.LastName) || wordArray.Contains(x.FirstName) || wordArray.Contains(x.MiddleName));
```