# {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsLetter(Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to get all items in the database using LINQ where the Title starts with special characters or number, I already tried the code below but it's not working.

Thanks

```
result = (from asset in _db.Query<Asset>()
                          where !char.IsLetter(asset.Title[0])
                          select new AssociatedItem { Id = asset.AssetId, Title = asset.Title, Type = Constants.FeedbackTypes.ASSET }).ToList();
```

Comment: Related posts - [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7259567/465053) & [Entity Framework Specification Pattern Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352764/465053)

Comment: Another related post - [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5899683/465053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because char.IsLetter is not a [dbFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx).

You can apply `where` after converting the results `ToList()`

```
result = (from asset in _db.Query<Asset>()                         
                      select new AssociatedItem { Id = asset.AssetId, Title = asset.Title, Type = Constants.FeedbackTypes.ASSET }).ToList()
.Where(a => !char.IsLetter(a.Title[0])).ToList();
```

PS: Try to identify some other where clause for the db query to limit the results.

Comment: @Jeff: That's why I said _Try to identify some other where clause for the db query to limit the results._. What he is trying to do is bad from SQL aspect too, not just from LINQ aspect. Do you know why it is bad from SQL aspect?

Answer (score 1):

I'd give the `SqlMethods` class from the `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient` namespace a shot.

```
result = (from asset in _db.Query<Asset>()
                     where !SqlMethods.Like(asset.Title, "[a-Z]%")
                     select 
                            new AssociatedItem 
                            { 
                                Id = asset.AssetId, 
                                Title = asset.Title, 
                                Type = Constants.FeedbackTypes.ASSET 
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: This solution may work. But we should encourage OP to find a different filtering criteria for the where clause. This kind of application of functions on indexed fields is a bad practice from SQL perspective.

Comment: Just to learn something new: why is this considered bad practice from SQL perspective?

Comment: Only sargable predicates should be used in this kind of situations. Otherwise you will not be able to get the advantage of an index. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: Well then basically I did the right thing anyway since my query is translating to a NOT LIKE operation. But I still could improve it by making it a LIKE statement