# LINQ to Entities using the SQL LIKE operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities, sql-like

I have this:

```
query = query.Where(s => s.ShowTypeDescription == showTypeDescription);
```

several times for different variables in order to build dynamic SQL.

How would I go about transforming the above to say:

```
query = query.Where(s => s.ShowTypeDescription **LIKE** showTypeDescription);
```

?

Comment: search is your friend - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493703/linq-to-entity-using-a-sql-like-operator?rq=1

Comment: that doesn't help me. I know about "Contains" but how would I implement that into the code I have?

Comment: If you knew about `Contains()` you wouldn't be asking this question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is to find a substring within another string, the best way to do this is with the `Contains` method:

```
query = query.Where(s => s.ShowTypeDescription.Contains(showTypeDescription));
```

Because the `String.Contains` method translates to:

```
CHARINDEX(ShowTypeDescription, @showTypeDescription) > 0
```

Which is roughly equivalent to:

```
ShowTypeDescription LIKE '%' + @showTypeDescription + '%'
```

**Update:** In Linq-to-SQL, you can use the [`SqlMethods.Like`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx) method:

```
query = query.Where(s => SqlMethods.Like(s.ShowTypeDescription, showTypeDescription));
```

This will directly translate to the SQL `LIKE` operator. Note, however, this won't work outside of Linq-to-SQL queries. Trying to call this method in other contexts will throw an exception.

Comment: any idea if i can make my own expression? i would pass a string

Comment: im not sure why but if i call do it in EF6 i get an error converting store expression Boolean like(System.String,System.String)

Comment: I guess EF uses Linq-to-Entity, while this `SqlMethods` only work with Linq-to-SQL. `StartsWith` works for me.

Answer (score 13):

```
query = query.Where(s => s.ShowTypeDescription.Contains(showTypeDescription));

   Contains() is translated LIKE '%term%'
   StartsWith() = LIKE 'term%'
   EndsWith()   = LIKE '%term'
```