# LINQ .Startswith or .Contains problems in VB.NET4

Tags: vb.net, linq, contains, startswith

This may be a newbie question...

In my code I can easily use "where Obj.Feld = String", but using "where Obj.Feld.StartsWith("a")" doesn't work. See the following two functions:

```
    Public Function EntriesByFileName(ByRef Database() As Entry, ByVal Filename As _
  String) As IEnumerable(Of Entry)
        Dim Result As IEnumerable(Of Entry) = From EntryObject In Database _
        Where (EntryObject.FileName = Filename) Select EntryObject
        Return Result
    End Function

    Public Function EntriesLikeFileName(ByRef Database() As Entry, ByVal _
      Filename As String) As IEnumerable(Of Entry)
        Filename = Filename.ToLower
        Dim Result As IEnumerable(Of Entry) = From EntryObject In Database _
          Where EntryObject.FileName.StartsWith("a") Select EntryObject
        Return Result
    End Function
```

The first function (byFileName) works fine. The second function (LikeFileName) doesn't. Using Startswith I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." What am I doing wrong?

Database is an array of Objects, a structure consisting of strings

Answer (score 4):

`EntryObject.FileName` can be `NULL`, so `EntryObject.FileName.StartsWith(..)` can throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Change the condition to first check for `NULL` eg

```
if EntryObject.FileName <> nothing AndAlso EntryObject.FileName.StartsWith(..)
```

Using `AndAlso` here employs short-circuiting, which means that if the first condition is not met, the second won't be evaluated and hence we can't get the `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I thought you needed `AndAlso` to get short-circuiting.

Comment: @Gabe Thanks, you're correct of course. I'm no expert on VB. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure Database does not contain any null entries. You can apply the = operator on null, but you cannot call any methods on it, so StartsWith() fails.

Answer (score 1):

looks like one of the `EntryObject` object has `FileName` property set to null. In first method it won't be detected because you can compare a null value to other value, but in second method, you are trying to invoke a method on a null object which will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linq to entities then I don't think it supports startswith or contains.  See this post  [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990451/problem-with-linq-to-entities-and-string-startswith)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem at hand.