# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my controller class

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private rikuEntities rk = new rikuEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new rikuEntities();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = db.emp.Select(c => new     
               SelectListItem
               {
                 Value = c.Id.ToString(), 
                 Text = c.name
               });
        ViewBag.CategoryID = items;
        return View();
    }
}
```

this is my view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("viewToController", "Home"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>emp</legend>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.Categories)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

whenever I run this program I get this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." in the statement  **@Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (IEnumerable) ViewBag.Categories)**. i am using entity framework mechanism for databse connection. please help me to find out the error...

Comment: I am having the same issue, I still don't know how to do the ".ToString()" method inside the expression. It returns the error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: There is a good answer in the topic bellow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110266/why-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you to use view models and strongly typed views instead of ViewBag. So start with defining your view model:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

then in the controller populate this view model:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new rikuEntities();
        var model = new EmployeeViewModel
        {
            Categories = db.emp.ToArray() // <-- you probably want categories here
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model EmployeeViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("viewToController", "Home"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>emp</legend>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                x => x.CategoryId,
                new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Id", "name")
            )
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sadly EF does not know how to convert `ToString()` to an SQL statement.

You must, therefore, use the embedded function [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.stringconvert.aspx).

There is no overload for `int` so you will need to typecast to `double` :-(

```
var items = from v in db.emp  
   select new SelectListItem
   {     
       Text = c.name,        
       Code = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.Id)
   };
```