# Why LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Getting error inside MVC3 web application.
`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

when i try to fetch values using EF from query :

```
public class DataRepository
    {
        public mydataEntities1 dbContext = new mydataEntities1();

        public List<SelectListItem> GetPricingSecurityID()
        {
        var pricingSecurityID = (from m in dbContext.Reporting_DailyNAV_Pricing
                                     select new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                                Text = m.PricingSecurityID.ToString(),
                                                Value = m.PricingSecurityID.ToString()
                                         });

        return pricingSecurityID.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That can't be converted to SQL. I guess, in theory, it could, but isn't implemented.

You just need to perform your projection after you have your results:

```
var pricingSecurityID = (from m in dbContext.Reporting_DailyNAV_Pricing
                                     select m.PricingSecurityID).AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Text = x.ToString(), Value = x.ToString() });
```

Comment: There's no need to call `ToList()` here - why build another list, when `AsEnumerable` will do the job with less overhead?

Comment: @JonSkeet It depends. If you need to operate on results right away or if you want to wait till actually compiler executes the query.

Comment: @MandeepJanjua: The OP is calling `ToList` at the end anyway to return a list - there's no point in calling `ToList().Select(...).ToList()`.

Answer (score 18):

If it's already a string, why are you bothering to call `ToString` in the first place? I suspect a translation wasn't included in LINQ to Entities because it's pointless. Change your select clause to:

```
select new SelectListItem
{
    Text = m.PricingSecurityID,
    Value = m.PricingSecurityID
}
```

If you *really* need to do something which isn't supported by LINQ to Entities, use `AsEnumerable` to transition from a database query to in-process:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetPricingSecurityID()
{
    return dbContext.Reporting_DailyNAV_Pricing
                    .Select(m => m.PricingSecurityID)
                    .AsEnumerable() // Rest of query is local
                    // Add calls to ToString() if you really need them...
                    .Select(id => new SelectListItem { Text = id, Value = id })
                    .ToList();
}
```

I agree with Jason's objections too, btw. You'd be better off returning a `List<string>` which is rendered elsewhere.

Also note that if you're *just* going to use a single `select` clause or just a `where` clause, query expressions really don't add much - calling the LINQ extension methods can end up with less clutter, particularly if you want to call methods which *aren't* supported in query expressions (such as `ToList`).

Comment: Are you reading `System.String ToString()` as meaning `PricingSecurityID` is already a `string`? I actually think it's referring to the return type of `ToString` and that `PricingSecurityID` is possibly (likely?) not already a `string`.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, that's my guess. Maybe I'm wrong, in which case my second piece of code (with ToString calls) would be the right way to go. I don't think your approach of just splitting the projection would help - it's still going to be executing in the database unless you materialize the query or use AsEnumerable.

Comment: I just tested it: The error message also mentions `System.String ToString()` if the source data type is *not* a string.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's trying to convert it to SQL, and it can't. Drop off the call to `ToString`, and do a projection before you return to the caller. So, replace your `select` clause with

```
select m.PricingSecurityID
```

and then say

```
return pricingSecurityID
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(x => x.ToString())
           .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x })
           .ToList();
```

Also, I note that you're mixing UI concerns and data querying concerns. This is generally a bad practice. Really, you should just be returning the list of IDs and let the UI portion of your code worry about finagling it into the right form.

Answer (score 4):

How about this.  In this example, both the VDN field in the db and the Skill field are integers. I'm looking for matches from both fields so I have 2 compares.

Include this:

```
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient; // needed to convert numbers to strings for linq
```

When comparing numbers do this:

```
        // Search Code
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                depts = depts.Where(d => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)d.VDN).Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                || SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)d.Skill).Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }
        // End Search Code
```

Workie.

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer to relate more closely with the question?  The connection isn't immediately clear.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly EF does not know how to convert .ToString() You must use embedded function SqlFunctions.StringConvert: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466292.aspx Also there is no overload for int so you must typecast to double :-(

```
var vendors = 
   from v in Vendors  
   select new
   {             
       Code = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)v.VendorId)
   };
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this question is answered and I agree that using `AsEnumerable()` is the way to go. However I would like to highlight a common scenario that I usually come across where `AsEnumerable()` is used inefficiently to resolve this error.

From [.NET Language-Integrated Query for Relational Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)

> The AsEnumerable() operator, unlike ToList() and ToArray(), does not cause execution of the query. It is still deferred. The AsEnumerable() operator merely changes the static typing of the query, turning a IQueryable  into an IEnumerable, tricking the compiler into treating the rest of the query as locally executed.

**References**

1. [Am I misunderstanding LINQ to SQL .AsEnumerable()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389855/am-i-misunderstanding-linq-to-sql-asenumerable/44400508#44400508)
2. [Understanding .AsEnumerable() in LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311244/understanding-asenumerable-in-linq-to-sql/3321136#3321136)

**Inefficient way**

```
IEnumerable<InvoiceDTO> inefficientEnumerable = 
     (from a in db.Invoices
     where a.Practice_Key == practiceKey.FirstOrDefault()
     select a
     ).AsEnumerable().
     Select(x => new InvoiceDTO
                             {
                                 InvoiceID = x.InvoiceID,
                                 PracticeShortName = x.Dim_Practice.Short_Name,
                                 InvoiceDate = x.InvoiceDate,
                                 InvoiceTotal = x.InvoiceAmount,
                                 IsApproved = x.IsApproved,
                                 InvoiceStatus = (
                                                  x.IsApproved == null ? "Pending" :
                                                  x.IsApproved == true ? "Approved" :
                                                  x.IsApproved == false ? "Rejected" : "Unknown"
                                                ),
                                 InvoicePeriodStartDateText = x.InvoicePeriodStart.ToShortDateString(),
                                 InvoicePeriodEndDateText = x.InvoicePeriodEnd.ToShortDateString(),
                                 InvoicePeriodStartDate = x.InvoicePeriodStart,
                                 InvoicePeriodEndDate = x.InvoicePeriodEnd
                             }
                             );

            invoices = inefficientEnumerable.ToList();
```

Here the `AsEnumerable` is used for the entire table. All the columns are getting selected eventhough they are not needed.

**Better Way**

```
 IQueryable<InvoiceDTO> invoicesQuery = 
   (from a in db.Invoices
   where a.Practice_Key == practiceKey.FirstOrDefault()
   select new InvoiceDTO
            {
             InvoiceID = a.InvoiceID,
             PracticeShortName = a.Dim_Practice.Short_Name,
             InvoiceDate = a.InvoiceDate,
             InvoiceTotal = a.InvoiceAmount,
             IsApproved = a.IsApproved,
             InvoiceStatus = (
                               a.IsApproved == null ? "Pending" :
                               a.IsApproved == true ? "Approved" :
                               a.IsApproved == false ? "Rejected" :"Unknown"
                               ),
             InvoicePeriodStartDate = a.InvoicePeriodStart,
             InvoicePeriodEndDate = a.InvoicePeriodEnd
          });


          IEnumerable<InvoiceDTO> betterEnumerable = invoicesQuery.AsEnumerable().
          Select(x => new InvoiceDTO
                                 {
                                     InvoiceID = x.InvoiceID,
                                     PracticeShortName = x.PracticeShortName,
                                     InvoiceDate = x.InvoiceDate,
                                     InvoiceTotal = x.InvoiceTotal,
                                     IsApproved = x.IsApproved,
                                     InvoiceStatus = x.InvoiceStatus,
                                     InvoicePeriodStartDateText = x.InvoicePeriodStartDate.ToShortDateString(),
                                     InvoicePeriodEndDateText = x.InvoicePeriodEndDate.ToShortDateString(),
                                     InvoicePeriodStartDate = x.InvoicePeriodStartDate,
                                     InvoicePeriodEndDate = x.InvoicePeriodEndDate
                                 }
                                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This using VB.NET, Important Point is you need to Get the results AsEnumerable as mentioned in Answers.

```
Dim _EventsDaysResult = From ED In TAdbContext.EventPolicies.AsEnumerable
                                    Where ED.EventID = EID
                                    Select New With {ED.EventID, 
                                    .DayInfo = 
                                    ED.EventDay.GetValueOrDefault.ToShortDateString & " ( " & ED.EventDayTitle & " ) "}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
return dbContext.Reporting_DailyNAV_Pricing.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = x.PricingSecurityID.ToString(),
    Value = x.PricingSecurityID.ToString()
}).ToList();
```