# LINQ 'AsEnumerable' and the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I am writing a LINQ query similar to the following:

```
var test = from o in dbcontext.Orders.AsEnumerable()
        where o.ID==1
        select new Order
        { 
             Name = GetName(o.ID)
        };
```

In order to call an external function within the LINQ query, I am using `AsEnumerable()` within the query.

I understand that normally the query is not executed until an enumeration function like `ToList()`, etc. is called. But here I am calling the enumeration *within* the query.

Can anyone tell me if it is considered bad practice to use `AsEnumerable()` like this? Will it suffer in performance compared to calling `ToList()` *after* creating the query?

Comment: Worth Reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110266/why-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring/43262421#43262421

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do

```
var ids = from o in dbcontext.Orders
          where o.ID==1
          select new { ID = o.ID }; 

var names = from i in ids.AsEnumerable()
            select new Order { Name = GetName(i.ID) };
```

i.e. do as much querying as possible in the database, and then only perform the ID-to-name transformation in C#.

Comment: In principal yes but, only if the type exposed by `dbContext.Orders` implements `IEnumerable` in s superior way to the standard `IEnumerable` extension. Since its not clear what type `dbContext.Orders` is, I can't say.