# Error Converting Enum to String in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query, which is using Entity Framework.

```
Analytic firstSent = (from a in Repository.Query<Analytic>()
                      where a.EntityType == "Proposal" &&
                      a.EntityId == Program.ActiveProposal.Id &&
                      a.Marker == AnalyticMarker.EmailProposalUrl.ToString()
                      orderby a.TimestampUtc
                      select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

At run time, I get the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

`a.Marker` is a string column, and `AnalyticMarker.EmailProposalUrl` is an enum value, and I want to compare that column against the name of that enum.

I understand that the conversion from an enum to a string is not supported by SQL, but why won't it resolve the value of this string and then pass the resulting string to SQL? That should work just fine.

Comment: sir, have you tried this? [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110266/why-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228318/linq-int-to-string)

Comment: Can you cast and assign it to a string variable BEFORE the Query?

Comment: @DaveA: Yes, that's what FloydPink suggested. I just don't see why it should be necessary.

Comment: def not necessary. easier. I'm a fan of that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var emailProposalUrl = AnalyticMarker.EmailProposalUrl.ToString();
Analytic firstSent = (from a in Repository.Query<Analytic>()
                      where a.EntityType == "Proposal" &&
                      a.EntityId == Program.ActiveProposal.Id &&
                      a.Marker == emailProposalUrl
                      orderby a.TimestampUtc
                      select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5899740/218882) is explaining the reason why this could work as well..

> The problem arises because `ToString()` isn't really executed, it is
>   turned into a [MethodGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c) and then parsed and translated to SQL.
>   Since there is no `ToString()` equivalent, the expression fails.

Comment: I was thinking about defining the string separately as you suggest, but I have several of these and it just seems a little awkward. What I don't understand is why LINQ isn't smart enough to resolve what it can in C# before constructing the SQL, similar to how the C# compiler resolves what constant expressions it can before generating code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the places where C# will normally resolve tostring for you, it normally takes an object. Here, for example though, you're asking it to compare a string to an enum. Although C# COULD call tostring(), its not correct for it to do so.

Think about if it was int you were trying to compare against, rather than an enum. You can't compare the number 1 and a string. (Well, you can, but it involves assumptions, which is the point; the language is just trying to prod you into making the logic that little more explicit)

Comment: I think you need to reread my question. I'm trying to compare a string against a string.

Comment: *fail* That will teach me to try to answer questions as I'm going off to bed. Apologies!