# Searching For A Record After A LINQ Query Exception

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm confused to why this is happening.  I'm new to LINQ so I'm clearly missing something here, that is probably pretty easy.  I've looked up help on the topic, but I don't really know what to ask so I haven't found any answers that really address my question.

**This doesn't work**

It throws an `EntityCommandExecutionException` when the `FirstOrDefault` method is executed.

```
var query = from band in context.BandsEntitySet
            where band.ID == 12345
            select band;

foreach (var item in query)
{
    string venueName = item.VenueName;

    var venue = context.VenueEntitySet.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Venue.Equals(venueName));

    if(venue != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Name + " is playing in " + venueName + " on the " + item.PlayDate);
        Debug.WriteLine("The address of " + venueName + " is " + venue.Address);
    }
}
```

**This works**

```
var query = from band in context.BandsEntitySet
                    where band.ID == 12345
                    select band;

var bandList = query.toList();

foreach (var item in bandList)
{
    string venueName = item.VenueName;

    var venue = context.VenueEntitySet.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Venue.Equals(venueName));

    if(venue != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Name + " is playing in " + venueName + " on the " + item.PlayDate);
        Debug.WriteLine("The address of " + venueName + " is " + venue.Address);
    }
}
```

**My question is simple:** Why is the exception being thrown? And why does creating a list from the query allow me to use the `FirstOrDefault` method?

**Exception Message:** `A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll`

I guess I am wrong in my assumption that query is a list?  Then what is it exactly?

**Here is the stack trace**

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at BandManagementProject.AutoUpdate.Dev() in c:\BandManagementProject\AutoUpdate.cs:line 99
   at BandManagementProject.AutoUpdate.Main(String[] args) in c:\BandManagementProject\AutoUpdate.cs:line 41
```

**Inner Exception**

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

**Conclusion**
I didn't close my LINQ query before executing additional queries.  Didn't realize I needed to do that.  I appreciate all the help!

thanks,
Justin

Comment: Can you post the exception message?

Comment: Why you looping but not using the item?

Comment: @GrantThomas This is just an example. When I try to search for a record in another entity set it throws an exception.

Comment: Posted my answer then re-read your question. It makes no sense if you are not using the item. I suspect your example is missing some crucial information. can you post something real that you are having a problem with?

Comment: And is there any more information in the stack trace? Is there an inner exception with more details?

Comment: What is r.Venue? Is it a String?

Comment: @Colin yes it is. It is the name of the venue.

Comment: It must have something to do with executing a second query against the context whilst the first is still active - remember that until you materialise (`ToList()`, etc) the connection on the context is still open. I bet if you check the `InnerException` property of that error you will get a pretty clear error message from the underlying DB Provider.

Comment: Can you check if there is anything attached to the `InnerException` property when the exception gets thrown (use the debugger, not just the stack trace) as that should hold more details about the underlying cause.

Comment: @StephenByrne yup that was it! Are you saying to simply print out the InnerException? Or is there a way to check it while the code is running? Sorry, new to Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm not sure you do need to close your connection unless you are triggering lazy loading. Is Venue marked virtual? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4868569/150342

Comment: @Justin - delighted you got it working! You can wrap code like that in a `try/catch` block, so when you catch the exception you can check if `InnerException` isn't null, and print it out or log it along with the rest of the exception. (You can of also check in VS during debugging, click the "View Details..." link when the exception notification pops up) Very generally speaking, if the framework you're invoking involves an abstraction of any kind (`Entity Framework`, abstracting `MySqlClient` in this case) then checking for `InnerException` to get the "real" error is always a good idea.

Comment: @Colin - the problem here is that, afaik, the `MySqlClient` doesn't support `MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets)` so therefore what might have worked if he were using full-blooded `SqlClient` will not necessarily work for him in this case. That's a slight leak in the EF abstraction :)

Comment: @Colin No, I don't think it is.  I just loaded the database and all the tables into my project using the Entity Data Model and didn't touch anything.

Comment: @StephenByrne if you write up your comment as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: @StephenByrne so iterating through an `IQueryable` and running another query inside the iteration will cause the exception even if you are not triggering a lazy load? (At least while `MultipleActiveResultSets=false`  - and it's always effectively false with `MySqlClient`)... This seems to suggest otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5438064/150342 ? Sorry if am I guilty of hijacking this question ;-)

Comment: @Colin this is all useful information :-)

Comment: @Colin - in that case, using the `.Include` loads all data using a single operation, so there is still only one active result set, it's just a lot bigger, because it contains all of the relevant data (hence will be slower, take up more memory, etc). And that is a really good question!

Comment: @Colin - actually I would say it's better to have Colin update his answer and then accept that, it keeps the problem and solution nice and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query is using Linq-To-Entities. Linq-To-Entities methods build an expression tree that is translated to sql when you enumerate. If you include something it can't translate to sql you will get an exception.  `ToString()` is an example.  [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10110266/150342)

Calling `ToList()` makes the enumeration occur. So the sql is run, it doesn't include anything that can't be translated, and the data is moved into memory. Now you are using Linq-To-Objects, and standard C# method calls are recognised

Try this:

`var venue = context.VenueEntitySet.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Venue == venueName))`

**EDIT** OK we know that wasn't the problem now - but another idea to consider is getting the data in one call to the database. Something like this:

```
        var query = from band in context.BandsEntitySet
                    //not sure the join makes sense. How come every band has a VenueName?
                    //join venue in context.VenueEntitySet 
                    //on band.VenueName equals venue.Name
                    //surely there should be a navigation property
                    from venue in band.Venues //using a navigation property
                    where band.ID == 12345
                    select new { 
                                   BandName = band.Name, 
                                   VenueName = venue.Name, 
                                   PlayDate = venue.PlayDate, 
                                   Address = venue.Address 
                               };

        foreach (var item in query)
        {                
            Debug.WriteLine(item.BandName + " is playing in " 
                           + item.VenueName + " on the " + item.PlayDate);
            Debug.WriteLine("The address of " + item.VenueName + " is " + item.Address);

        }
```

And that should also avoid the problem with multiple open DataReaders

Comment: Thanks, but that throws the same exception. Any other ideas? I see what you are saying though.

Comment: I just tested the solution from Colin on AdventureWorks2008R2, with the `DimAccounts` table and used `var venue = bandList.FirstOrDefault (l => l.AccountKey.Equals(15));` Totally worked.

Comment: @Serv yes my bad. I saw that ToList() solved the problem and thought it was the common problem with `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ` There is something else going on..

Comment: +1 for doing in in a single operation with a `join` - that's using yer noggin.

Comment: This is interesting, and would greatly improve the readability and efficiency of my code, but by issue is that there can be multiple venues per band. When I run your code, it prints out every VenueName, PlayDate and Address even if it isn't found in the Bands Table.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Justin - you could use `GroupBy` to group by Band, and then loop through that group and list off each venue per band. Let us know via comments if you are stuck.

Comment: @Justin yes the linq as written wasn't joining properly. I have re-written it with a proper join - but the join doesn't make sense to me so I've commented it out. I usually find that using navigatiuon properties rather than joins makes more sense to me so I've assumed that you can add one named "Venues"

Comment: Thanks so much for everyone's help! This has been invaluable and now everything is working properly. :-)