# Linq Queries containing "AsEnumerable()" equivalence

Tags: c#, linq, asenumerable

Are this 2 queries functionally equivalent?

1)

```
var z=Categories
         .Where(s=>s.CategoryName.Contains("a"))
         .OrderBy(s => s.CategoryName).AsEnumerable()
         .Select((x,i)=>new {x.CategoryName,Rank=i});
```

2)

```
var z=Categories.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(s=>s.CategoryName.Contains("a"))
         .OrderBy(s => s.CategoryName)
         .Select((x,i)=>new {x.CategoryName,Rank=i});
```

I mean, does the order of "AsNumerable()" in the query change the number of data items retrieved from the client, or the way they are retrieved?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Yes, the order matters.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311244/understanding-asenumerable-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: This depends on your LINQ provider, but you don't specify which one you're using. LINQ to SQL? Entity Framework? Something else?

Comment: LINQ to SQL..., yep i should say it.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110266/why-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring/43262421#43262421

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are this 2 queries functionally equivalent?

If by equivalent you means to the final results, then probably yes (depending how the provider implements those operations), the difference is in the second query you are using in-memory extensions.

> I mean, does the order of "AsNumerable()" in the query change the
>   number of data items retrieved from the client, or the way they are
>   retrieved?

Yes, in the first query, `Where` and `OrderBy` will be translated to *SQL* and the `Select` will be executed in memory.

In your second query all the information from the database is brought to memory, then is filtered and transformed in memory.

---

`Categories` is probably an `IQueryable`, so you will be using the extensions in `Queryable` class. this version of the extensions receive a `Expression` as parameter, and these expression trees is what allows transform your code to sql queries.

`AsEnumerable()` returns the object as an `IEnumerable`, so you will be using the extensions in `Enumerable` class that are executed directly in memory.

Comment: `If by equivalent you means to the final results, then yes, the difference is in the second query you are using in-memory extensions;` That's not necessarily true.  It's possible for the query provider to have slightly (or possibly even significantly) different semantics than the in-memory equivalents of those operations.

Comment: @Servy: It's true, Updated the answer.

Comment: Also `AsEnumerable` doesn't "transform" the collection, it just forces the compiler to bind subseuent calls to `IEnumerable` extension methods instead of `IQueryable`.

Comment: @Servy Good observation.  Something that comes to mind would be the equality operation on a string.  The default collation for SQL server is case insensitive, whereas the default string equality comparer IS case sensitive.  That means `Where(s => s.SomeString.Equals("Foo"))` could produce different results depending on the order that the extension methods were chained.

Comment: @S.Bozzoni: You,re welcome, please consider the answer as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do the same thing but in different ways. The first query do all the selection,ordering and conditions in the SQL database itself.

However the second code segment fetches all the rows from the database and store it in the memory. Then after it sorts, orders, and apply conditions to the fetched data i.e now in the memory.

AsEnumerable() breaks the query into two parts:

1. The Inside-Part(query before AsEnumerable) is executed as LINQ-to-SQL
2. The Outside-Part(query after AsEnumerable) is executed as LINQ-to-Objects