# Creating a collection of SelectListItem with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display a dropdown list of users in my view. Here is the code I'm using in my controller method:

```
var users = _usersRepository.Users.Select(u => new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,
                                        Value = u.UserID.ToString()
                                    }

return View(new MyViewModel { Users = users });
```

I get an error trying to convert `UserID` to a string:

> **LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

How I create a collection of `SelectListItem` from my entities?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`ToString()` can only be used in Linq to Objects.  A simple solution is to insert `.ToList()` as follows:

```
var users = _usersRepository.Users.ToList().Select(u => new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,
                                        Value = u.UserID.ToString()
                                    });

return View(new MyViewModel { Users = users });
```

This is going to return all users from your User table.  If you can reduce the amount of users obtained from the database your query will be more efficient, e.g.

```
var users = _usersRepository.Users.Where( u => .... ).ToList().Select(u => new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,
                                        Value = u.UserID.ToString()
                                    });

return View(new MyViewModel { Users = users });
```

Comment: if you don't want to receive all columns you can also use :          `var users = (from u in _usersRepository.Users where .... select new {u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.UserID}).ToList().Select(u => new SelectListItem { Text = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName, Value = u.UserID.ToString() });`

Comment: What if we want it Distinct by `FirstName`?

Comment: @Halter You wouldn't be able to do that in a one-liner with Linq. After getting your Text/Value pairs, you'd have to iterate through each item, add it to a List, then loop through your Linq result again and check if the List contained your item, already - adding the items to a new "corrected list" if they were ok.

Answer (score 9):

I think you're looking for [`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx)

```
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;

var users = _usersRepository.Users.Select(u => new SelectListItem
                                    {
                                        Text = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,
                                        Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?)u.UserID)
                                    }

return View(new MyViewModel { Users = users });
```

Comment: Will this preserve deferred execution of the query, though?  Because if so (I honestly don't know off the top of my head), this might be a better option if that is important.

Comment: Deferred execution is preserved. LINQ to Entities providers are able to parse the methods of `SqlFunctions` into their equivalent SQL. So you are able to compose and execute this query the same as a more typical query.

Comment: Good to know!  Bookmarking this question for future reference, thanks for the clarification!