# Multi Column DropDownListFor MVC 4 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have done a single list DropDownList in MVC 4 Using razor

```
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.COAId, (SelectList)ViewBag.clientsList, "Please Select Client")</td>
```

I am getting items from database, now i want to add second column of CITY with tha name of client, how can i make it multicolumn?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC SelectList combining multiple columns in text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727285/mvc-selectlist-combining-multiple-columns-in-text-field)

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

```
var clients = db.ClientsTbls
        .Select(s => new
            {
            Text = s.Name + "-" + s.City,
            Value = s.clientId
        })
        .ToList();

ViewBag.clientsList= new SelectList(clients, "Value", "Text");
```

**View**

```
<td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.COAId, (SelectList)ViewBag.clientsList, "Please Select Client")</td>
```

Comment: how can it show multi column drop down? i think it should only show single column