# How to use Display Text property in SelectList

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, selectlist

Is there a better way of using `Value` and `Text` properties of [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) than what I'm doing in my following View? I feel like I'm doing some extra work than it should be.

**Note**: I'm aware of other ways of using dropdowns with `Value` and `Text`. This question is only related to on how to achieve the same while using `SelectList`

```
...
var customersList = _context.Customers.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.LastName, Text = c.FullName });

MyViewModel.lstCustomers = new SelectList(customersList , "Value", "Text");
...
return View(MyViewModel);
```

I found similar methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12727352/1232087) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12727818/1232087).

Comment: `customersList` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Using `new SelectList(...)` to create another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is just pointless extra overhead. Your `lstCustomers` property should be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` since that is all that is required by the `DropDownListFor()` method in your view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's what I was worried about - doing unnecessary extra work. If I were to use `SelectList`, how should I use `Value` and `Text` attributes?

Comment: Did you not understand my comment? Its the use of new `SelectList()` which is pointless. To generate a `<select>`, you need a property which is `IEnumerable<SelectLitsItem>` - you already have it - that is what your `var customersList = ...` code does. `SelectList` **is** `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and the 2nd line of your code just creates another identical one.

Comment: And you cannot use `new SelectList(...)` for a collection of complex objects unless you don't specify the 2nd and 3rd parameters - it would just generate all `<option>System.MVC.SelectListItem</option>` because if you omit the 2nd and 3rd parameters it uses the `.ToString()` of the objects in the collection to generate the options display text

Comment: You either do `MyViewModel.lstCustomers = _context.Customers.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.LastName, Text = c.FullName });` or you do `MyViewModel.lstCustomers = new SelectList(_context.Customers, "LastName", "FullName");` not both

Comment: @StephenMuecke Your previous comment answered what I was looking for. That should be a response instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HtmlHelper` methods for generating a `<select>` element (`@Html.DropDownListFor()` etc) expect an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as one of the parameters, therefore your `lstCustomers` should also be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> lstCustomers { get; set; }
```

You first line of code

```
var customersList = _context.Customers.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.LastName, Text = c.FullName });
```

is already generating that, so all that is required is

```
MyViewModel.lstCustomers = customersList;
```

You use of `new SelectList(customersList , "Value", "Text");` is just creating another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one and is unnecessary extra overhead. (`SelectList` **is** `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and is just a wrapper around it to provide constructors to generate the collection).

If you want to use `SelectList` constructor then change your code to

```
var customersList = _context.Customers;
MyViewModel.lstCustomers = new SelectList(customersList , "LastName", "FullName");
```

Both will generate the same output. The difference between the methods is that the `SelectList` constructor uses reflection to determine which properties to use for the options value and display text, so is fractionally slower, and it uses 'magic strings' so is not strongly typed. The benefit is that its a little less verbose.

Comment: I've decided to use your last example; though fractionally slower - I like it's being less verbose. Thanks for details as, like myself, it should benefit other readers, as well.

Comment: Yes, it really comes down to personal preference