# LINQ query (or lambda expression) to return records that match a list

Tags: linq, lambda

I have a list of strings (converted from Guid) that contains the ID's of items I want to pull from my table.
Then, in my LINQ query, I am trying to figure out how to do an in clause to pull records that are in that list.
Here is the LINQ

```
var RegionRequests = (from r in db.course_requests
                      where PendingIdList.Contains(r.request_state.ToString())
                      select r).ToList();
```

It builds, but I get a run error: "System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression".
I would prefer to compare guid to guid, but that gets me nowhere.
Can this be converted to a lambda expression? If that is best, how?

Comment: Why does a type that is system.string need to do a ToString anyways?

Comment: It's a Guid, I converted to string hoping it would work with string, because it did not work with Guid.

Comment: Have you seen this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method**??

Comment: I'm not uderstand what means "because it did not work with Guid" Entity framework can work with Guid. And your query without ToString must work. Could you show your entity model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to Entites tries to convert your expression to an SQL Statement. Your server didn't know the stored procedure `ToString()`.

Fix:

```
var regionRequests =
    from r in db.course_requests.ToList()
    where PendingIdList.Contains(r.request_state.ToString())
    select r;
```

With `db.course_requests.ToList()` you force LINQ to materialize your database data (if big table, you gonna have a bad time) and the `ToString()` is executed in the object context.

Answer (score 0):

You stated: I have a list of strings (converted from Guid) ...

Can you NOT convert them into strings and keep it as a List< System.Guid>??  Then you can do this (assuming PendingIdGuidList is List< System.Guid>:

```
var regionRequets = (from r in db.course_requests
                     join p in PendingIdGuidList on u.request_state equals p
                     select r).ToList();
```

Edited to add:

I ran a test on this using the following code:

```
var db = new EntityModels.MapleCreekEntities();

List<System.Guid> PendingIdGuidList = 
    new List<System.Guid>() { 
        System.Guid.Parse("77dfd79e-2d61-40b9-ac23-36eb53dc55bc"), 
        System.Guid.Parse("cd409b96-de92-4fd7-8870-aa42eb5b8751") 
    };

var regionRequets = (from r in db.Users
                     join p in PendingIdGuidList on r.Test equals p
                     select r).ToList();
```

Users is a table in my database.  I added a column called Test as a Uniqueidentifier data type, then modified 2 records with the following Guids.

I know it's not exactly a 1:1 of what the OP is doing, but pretty close.  Here is the profiled SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[UserLogin] AS [UserLogin], 
[Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
[Extent1].[Test] AS [Test]
FROM  [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN  (SELECT 
    cast('77dfd79e-2d61-40b9-ac23-36eb53dc55bc' as uniqueidentifier) AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    cast('cd409b96-de92-4fd7-8870-aa42eb5b8751' as uniqueidentifier) AS [C1]
    FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]) AS [UnionAll1] ON [Extent1].[Test] = [UnionAll1].[C1]
```

Comment: Assuming db.course_requests is an IQueryable in the database and PendingIdGuidList is an in memory collection, you can't join them this way. The preferred solution is to use Contains in the Where clause rather than a join.

Comment: Actually, it works just fine.  I just ran a test and viewed it in my profiler.  See my modified answer for what SQL Server did.