# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Method name' method

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I'm having a similar problem that was asked here: 
[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method)

I'm trying to paginate my source, but in my case, I can't put the result of `GetPropertyValue` in a variable, because I need `x` to do that:

```
public IEnumerable<TModel> Paginate(IQueryable<TModel> source, ref int totalPages, int pageIndex, int pageSize, string sortfield, SortDirection? sortdir)
{
    totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(source.Count() / (double)pageSize);

    if (sortdir == SortDirection.Descending)
    {
         return source.OrderByDescending(x => GetPropertyValue(x, sortfield)).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
         return source.OrderBy(x => GetPropertyValue(x, sortfield)).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    }
}

private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string name)
{
    return obj == null ? null : obj.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

What could I do, in this case?

Comment: What/where exactly is the issue you are getting? It looks as though your getting a not all paths return a value?

Comment: I'm getting a "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Method name' method", more specifically the method "GetPropertyValue".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lambda Expressions (Those are used within Where, OrderBy etc) cannot contain any C# specific code, they can only contain expression tree, which is translated to SQL. You cannot call any arbitrary methods there, except the ones that are mentioned by EF documentation such as SqlFunctions etc.

In order to do sorting with a field name at runtime, you have to create a lambda expression at runtime and pass it on.

```
public IEnumerable<TModel> Paginate(IQueryable<TModel> source, ref int totalPages, int pageIndex, int pageSize, string sortfield, SortDirection? sortdir)
{
    totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(source.Count() / (double)pageSize);

    if (sortdir == SortDirection.Descending)
    {
         return source.OrderByDescending(sortfield).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
         return source.OrderBy(sortfield).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    }
}


public static class QueryableHelper
{
    public static IQueryable<TModel> OrderBy<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> q, string name)
    {
        Type entityType = typeof(TModel);
        PropertyInfo p = entityType.GetProperty(name);
        MethodInfo m = typeof(QueryableHelper).GetMethod("OrderByProperty").MakeGenericMethod(entityType, p.PropertyType);
        return(IQueryable<TModel>) m.Invoke(null, new object[] { q, p });
    }

    public static IQueryable<TModel> OrderByDescending<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> q, string name)
    {
        Type entityType = typeof(TModel);
        PropertyInfo p = entityType.GetProperty(name);
        MethodInfo m = typeof(QueryableHelper).GetMethod("OrderByPropertyDescending").MakeGenericMethod(entityType, p.PropertyType);
        return (IQueryable<TModel>)m.Invoke(null, new object[] { q, p });
    }

    public static IQueryable<TModel> OrderByPropertyDescending<TModel, TRet>(IQueryable<TModel> q, PropertyInfo p)
    {
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel));
        Expression se = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(pe, p), typeof(object));
        return q.OrderByDescending(Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TRet>>(se, pe));
    }

    public static IQueryable<TModel> OrderByProperty<TModel, TRet>(IQueryable<TModel> q, PropertyInfo p)
    {
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel));
        Expression se = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(pe, p), typeof(object));
        return q.OrderBy(Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TRet>>(se, pe));
    }
}
```

This solution only works on single level of property, but if you want nested levels than it needs more work, perhaps you can look at following SDK which does all of that.

However if you take a look at Entity REST SDK itself, it has many things and all the things that you might need. Disclaimer: I am the Author.

https://entityrestsdk.codeplex.com

Comment: Almost worked. Now I'm getting a "Expression of type 'System.Int64' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'".

I changed `Func<TModel,object>>` to `Func<TModel,Int64>>` and it worked, but I don't know the type of the object that will be passed to the function. Could be a `String`, for example. Anyway to workaround this?

Comment: Can you try now? I have modified it little. I am leaving home for the day, if it works great, otherwise I will try to post solution, that is little larger, but that will be tomorrow.

Comment: Great, you've got way too little points for this fabulous answer!

Comment: Seems like it can't handle different sort property types. I also get an error  "Expression of type 'System.Int' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'".

Comment: Replacing with this works for me: `Expression se = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(pe, p), typeof(TRet));`

Comment: It sure would be nice to know how to make it case insensitive :)

Comment: Replacing with this works for me: Expression se = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(pe, p), typeof(TRet));

Also worked for me with a DateTime attribute!

Comment: I am using EF 6.2. Replacing typeof(object) with p.PropertyType did the job for me. Great Work man.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using reflection, you should dynamically create an `Expression<Func<TSource, TOrder>>` and pass it to `OrderBy`.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx) to understand how create a dynamic query.

Comment: I tried building expression but Expression.Lambda returns Expression<Func<object, object>> instead of Expression<Func<TDto, TKey>>