# Dynamic order linq VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq, entity-framework-4

im trying to do a dynamic order in linq using VB 
this is my code snipet

```
Dim registros = From d In ctx.EMO_RegistroEMPO
Return registros.AsQueryable().OrderBy(Function(EMO_RegistroEMPO) EMO_RegistroEMPO.GetType().GetProperty(pSortExpression)).ToList
```

but i got this error at execution:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo GetProperty(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: You need to build an expression tree.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Method name' method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977414/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-method-name-method)

Comment: Have a look here: How to: Use Expression Trees to Build Dynamic Queries (C# and Visual Basic) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx