# How do i create the following LINQ expression dynamically?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-6

I need the following C# code to be translated to a valid Entity Framework 6 expression:

```
(f => f.GetType().GetProperty(stringParamter).GetValue(f).ToString() == anotherStringParameter)
```

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977414/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-method-name-method) did it for the "Order By" part, but i cant seem to figure it out for the "where" part...

Generically speaking what i am trying to achieve here is a form of dynamic query where the user will "pick" properties to filter in a "dropbox", supply the filter-value and hit query... usually people do like `f => f.TargetProp == userValue` but i can't do that when i dont know which one it is...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to construct the expression tree that represents the access to the property:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> PropertyEquals<T>(
    string propertyName, string valueToCompare)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, propertyName)
        , Expression.Constant(valueToCompare));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
}
```

This allows you to write:

```
query = query.Where(PropertyEquals<EntityType>(stringParameter, anotherString));
```

Comment: what if i want to compare to a fixed/pre-determined sub-property? like: instead of `Expression.Property(param, propertyName)` something like `Expression.Property(param, propertyName.Title)`

Comment: @Leonardo Then use two `Expression.Property` calls to access the fixed property of the result of the previous property access.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the Dynamic Link Library?  It allows you to compose expressions as strings instead of lambda expressions.

Examples:

```
var query = baseQuery.Where("Id=5");

var query = baseQuery.Where("Id=@0", 5);
```

I've been keeping an updated version of Microsoft's Dynamic Linq example at https://github.com/NArnott/System.Linq.Dynamic in case you are interested, and it's also available on NuGet.

Comment: I didn't know that! I'll check it out!