# Using a dynamic value for the Model property in a Lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I'm trying to dynamically generate a model property in my Lambda express. In my controller I have the following method:

```
public ActionResult FilterSubCategory(string filter, string selected)
{
    IList<Item> model = db.Items.Where(p => p.Make == selected).ToList();
    var viewModel = Mapper.Map<IList<ItemViewModel>>(model);
    return View("~/Views/Phone/Index.cshtml", viewModel);
}
```

I want to use this method to filter my page's column so I'm passing the filter(model property to filter) and the actual selected property value.

I want to replace the **'Make'** ('hardcoded' here) here with the value of the **filter** string passed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered usage of [Dynamic LINQ](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i create the following LINQ expression dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916231/how-do-i-create-the-following-linq-expression-dynamically)

Comment: @Servy Thank you for the link. That solution worked wonderfully. Sorry for the duplicate! Upvoted here and in Original thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

```
public static Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> GenerateModelExpression<TModel, TProperty>(PropertyInfo property)
{
     ParameterExpression fieldName = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "m");

     var propertyExpr = Expression.Property(itemExpr, property.Name);

     return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TProperty>>(propertyExpr, fieldName);
}
```

The property parameter would be 'Make' in your case which you can get using reflection.

https://github.com/AmmarCSE/razor-grid

**Edit**

After reviewing the question more precisely and referencing former answery by @Servy, [How do i create the following LINQ expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916231/how-do-i-create-the-following-linq-expression-dynamically), here is a solution:

```
public static Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> GenerateModelExpression<TModel, TProperty>(string filter, string select)
{
     ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel), "m");
     var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, typeof(TModel).GetProperty(filter))
      , Expression.Constant(select));

     return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TProperty>>(body, param);
}
```

Comment: This is effectively a custom `Select`, and doesn't compare that property value to the value to filter on.

Comment: Hey @Servy, I thought the user was asking how to dynamically construct the lambda expression itself?

Comment: He's asking how to filter a query where a property (determined by its string name) is equal to a string value.  This doesn't do that.

Comment: @Servy, you are right and I overlooked that. How about something like typeof(TModel).GetProperty(filter)?

Comment: I fail to see how that code would solve this problem.

Comment: @Servy, with my code above, he can pass a string and then use typeof(TModel).GetProperty(param) to generate his expression. Afterall, the questioner said "I want to replace the 'Make' ('hardcoded' here) here with the value of the filter string passed. Is there a way to do this?"

Comment: Yes, there most certainly are ways to do this, you just aren't doing them.  You're getting the property value dynamically *but you're not using it*.  He needs to use it to compare its value with a known string value.  You have skipped that step.  This is just half of the solution.