# Call method directly - MakeGenericMethod

Tags: c#, function, lambda, delegates, expression

I wrote the code below using this answer:
[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Method name' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977414/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-method-name-method)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class to assit with ordering
    /// </summary>
    public static class QueryableHelper
    {
        public static IOrderedQueryable<TModel> OrderBy<TModel>(this IQueryable<TModel> q, string name, string orderType)
        {
            Type entityType = typeof(TModel);
            PropertyInfo p = entityType.GetProperty(name);
            MethodInfo m = typeof(QueryableHelper).GetMethod(orderType).MakeGenericMethod(entityType, p.PropertyType);
            return (IOrderedQueryable<TModel>)m.Invoke(null, new object[] { q, p });
        }

        public static IOrderedQueryable<TModel> OrderByPropertyDescending<TModel, TRet>(IQueryable<TModel> q, PropertyInfo p)
        {
            var expression = GetExpression<TModel, TRet>(q, p);
            return q.OrderByDescending(expression);
        }

        public static IOrderedQueryable<TModel> OrderByProperty<TModel, TRet>(IQueryable<TModel> q, PropertyInfo p)
        {
            var expression = GetExpression<TModel, TRet>(q, p);
            return q.OrderBy(expression);
        }

        private static Expression<Func<TModel, TRet>> GetExpression<TModel, TRet>(IQueryable<TModel> q, PropertyInfo p)
        {
            ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TModel));
            Expression se = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(pe, p), typeof(TRet));
            var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TRet>>(se, pe);
            return expression;
        }
    }
```

I have removed some of the repetition, but there is still more I can remove.

I want to call this function directly:

```
OrderByPropertyDescending
```

Currently it is being called by this line:

```
MethodInfo m = typeof(QueryableHelper).GetMethod(orderType).MakeGenericMethod(entityType, p.PropertyType);
```

Is there a way to call this function directly eg like this:

```
var res = OrderByPropertyDescending<TModel, TRet>(q, p);
```

My problem is that I do not know what to pass in for `TRet`

Any ideas?

Comment: How about the type of the property you want to order by?

Comment: If you don‘t know it at Compiler-time it’s Not possible. You could use an Interface, but Then all Return-values have to fullfill it.

Comment: @Nikolaus I want to call orderbydescending

Comment: Because of this Limitations Reflections are that usefull. ;-)

Comment: If you know, what Type the Property is you could write: string/DateTime/... whatever it is.

Comment: What if you'll take not `PropertyInfo` as parameter, but a `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> property`, so the call will be `OrderByPropertyDescending(model, model => model.X)`, this way generic arguments will be autofigured. Then, however you'll need to parse given `expression`, hoping it's simple property getter and fetch property info out of there.

Comment: @Quercus I think that is what I am looking for - if you provide an answer for that I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` as a type for `property` instead of `PropertyInfo`.

That will result in calls like: `OrderByPropertyDescending(model, model => model.X)`, where all generic arguments are automatically figured.

Then, you'll need to fetch `PropertyInfo` from given expression, so you'll just need to check type of given expression.

I've seen such an idea in `Caliburn.Micro` - see, for example, their `ExpressionExtensions`: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro.Core/ExpressionExtensions.cs

Actually, their `GetMemberInfo` will work for you.