# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(Int32)' method

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, runtime-error

I have search box which I want to return results based on TicketID. However, when trying to convert the TicketID to string to compare it against the search term string, I receive this error...

Here is my method:

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(Ticket ticket, string term)
{
    var searchTickets = db.Tickets
        .Where(t => t.StatusID != 3 && 
            Convert.ToString(t.TicketID).StartsWith(term))
        .Take(10)
        .Select(t => new
        {
            label = t.Summary
        });

    return Json(searchTickets, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I have tried other suggestions on similar posts such as the `SqlFunctions.StringConvert()` extension method, however, this throws a syntax error before the project is even built...

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: You should use `SqlFunctions` indeed, what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
Using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;


 var searchTickets = db.Tickets
        .Where(t => t.StatusID != 3 && 
            SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)t.TicketID).StartsWith(term)
        .Take(10)
        .Select(t => new
        {
            label = t.Summary
        });
```

With EF 4 you can use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`. There is no overload for `int` so you need to cast to a `double` or a `decimal`.

Comment: I've realized why this method wasn't working for me this first time I tried it! I was missing the Using statement 

Using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;

Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes, works fine now, I just needed to include the correct using statement :D

Comment: can you write the namespace for SqlFunction so i add it here for others

Comment: Sure, it is: `Using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;`