# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method,and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, tostring

```
allList = allList.Where(c => isAdvertSearchable 
  && c.tblAdvert.AdvertTitle.ToLower().Trim().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
  || isTranastionTypeSearchable 
  && c.IsActive.ToString().ToLower().Trim().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
  || (c.Amount.ToString().ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower().ToString()) 
  || param.sSearch == "")
  || isTranastionIDSearchable 
  && c.TransactionId.ToLower().Trim().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
```

Comment: try to put code with in { } brackets

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method)

Answer (score 1):

**LINQ** is complaining about not being able to translate `ToString` to **T-SQL**.

Use

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert(param.sSearch.ToLower())
```

**SqlFunctions Class**
Provides common language runtime (CLR) methods that call functions in the database in LINQ to Entities queries.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx