# Concatenate string in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a db call that returns me an object. I use linq to cast that object how I want it

```
var result = queryResult.OrderBy(c => c.TariffName)
                        .Take(count)
                        .Select(c => new
                            {
                                Text = c.TariffName,
                                Key = c.TariffId,
                                Price = c.LineRental
                            });

var list = result.ToList();
```

I now want to add the line rental to the tariff name show that it shows like:

myTariff - 12.99

when I try and do this though I can make this change ok:

```
Text = c.TariffName + " - ",
```

but when I try and add the line rental I get problems that linq won't recognise the ToString(). I need it to look like:

```
Text = c.TariffName + " - " + c.LineRental.ToString(),
```

I understand that linq won't recognise the ToString() method from reading [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method) but how do I change this given I can't set it as a string prior to the linq query?

Comment: You can use loop to fill the result object. In loops's body you can use `Text = c.TariffName + " - " + c.LineRental.ToString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the query result to a list first then use `select` to make the `toString` work.

```
var result = queryResult.OrderBy(c => c.TariffName)
                        .Take(count);
var list = result.ToList().Select(c => new
                            {
                                Text = c.TariffName + " - " + c.LineRental.ToString(),
                                Key = c.TariffId,
                                Price = c.LineRental
                            });
```

Answer (score -1):

What is happening linq trying to execute your select statement on the database query level, and it does not know how to transform your `.Select` lambda to `select` part of sql statement.

Easiest thing you can do is first query required fields, call `.ToList()` on query to execute it and perform projection after that.

```
var result = queryResult.OrderBy(c => c.TariffName)
                    .Take(count)

                    .Select(c => new
                        {
                            Text = c.TariffName,
                            Key = c.TariffId,
                            Price = c.LineRental
                        });

var list = result.ToList().Select(c=>new {
          Text = string.Format("{0} - {1}", c.Text, c.Price),
          Key=Key,
          Price=Price
});
```

Comment: You're loading the whole table into memory just because you don't know how to concatenate both.