# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method. And this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, .net

when i try to run the code

```
public static DalUser ToDalUser(this User ormUser)
    {
        return new DalUser()
        {
            Id = ormUser.Id,
            FirstName = ormUser.FirstName,
            LastName = ormUser.LastName,
            About = ormUser.About,
            Email = ormUser.Email,
            Password = ormUser.Password,
            Roles = ormUser.Roles.Select(role => role.ToDalRole())
        };
    }
```

error occurs

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'DAL.Interface.DTO.DalUser ToDalUser(ORM.User)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

in View

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.About)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.Role)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

what's the problem? please, help!

Comment: `.ToDalRole()` cannot be mapped to SQL.  You'd need to map post retrieval.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899683/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method)

Comment: @DavidL sorry, but i don't understand, how to do this. can you explain me in detail, please?

Comment: I removed that prior comment since it referenced a deeper method call than the one in the actual error.

Comment: @Kevin but it's written that userEntity.Role implements IEnumerable

Comment: @PavelYakimovich can you post the code that is throwing the exception, i.e. the query you are trying to run? That would help the community provide feedback.

Comment: @MikeSackton i don't even know. i just try to run my asp.net mvc app and this error occurs before start

Comment: @MikeSackton i added code that throws the exception

Comment: which line exactly throws the exception?

Comment: @mxmissile foreach (var item in Model)

Comment: Post your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many Roles you have, if not that many you should be able to do this:

```
Roles = ormUser.Roles
  .ToArray()
  .Select(role => role.ToDalRole())
```

The reason being the `ToArray()` method will load all the Roles into memory before calling `Select`. If you have thousands (or even hundreds) this is not recommended.