# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Object getMethod' method

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have the following entity code where i want to return a formatted string based on a custom a function that return a string:

```
var query =
               from a in db.Authors
               join b in db.Books
               on a.id equals b.atuhorId into ab
               from item in ab.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new
               {
                   id =  a.id,
                   authorName= a.name,
                   bookName = b.name,
                   formatted_book = item.id != null ?  model.getFormatedBook(item.id) : "N/A",
                   },

               };
```

But i got an error like mentioned in my post title.
Is there a cast that i can put inside my entity code for the ***getFormatedBook(item.id)*** ? I tried ***getFormatedBook(item.id).ToString()*** but with no success

Thanks

Comment: could you post `getFormatedBook` method?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Entity is unable to call outside methods as a part of a query. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12641286/1202275 for possible workarounds.