# How can I use Entity Framework LINQ to find rows where a column starts with a string?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am currently using this to query data in SQL Server:

```
var query = db.Phrases.AsQueryable();
if (options.Romaji != null) query = query
            .Where(w => w.Romaji.Contains(options.Romaji));
```

How can I change this so that instead of looking for a row with a column with a string in it that it looks for a row with a column which starts with the string in options.Romaji?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with LINQ to Entities and String.StartsWith](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990451/problem-with-linq-to-entities-and-string-startswith)

Comment: It sounds as you want to use `w.Romaji.StartsWith(options.Romaji)`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `StartsWith()` method instead of contains.

```
query = query.Where(w => w.Romaji.StartsWith(options.Romaji));
```