# How to match Pattern in LINQ

Tags: linq, oracle11g, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have been working in SQL and had recently started LINQ C# queries.
I'm trying to write a LINQ query to find all the employees whose job's name starts with A. 
I want similar results to this SQL query

**SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT empno, ename, job, sal 
FROM   emp
WHERE job LIKE 'A%';
```

**LINQ VERSION**

```
from query in conn,EMPs
where query.JOB like 'A%'
select new
{
    query.EMPNO, query.ENAME, query.JOB, query.SAL
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the oracle provider, but you could try either `where query.Job.StartsWith("A")` or `where SqlMethods.Like(query.Job, "A%")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the SQL like syntax you can do this way:

```
from x in context
where x.JOB.StartsWith("A")
select new
{
    x.EMPNO, x.ENAME, x.JOB, x.SAL
};
```

Or if you don't need projection for the results you can do simply:

```
from x in context
where x.JOB.StartsWith("A")
select x;
```

Or you can switch to fluent version like the guy that commented your post did.

**EDIT**

You could also find useful info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990451/problem-with-linq-to-entities-and-string-startswith) where they talk about this functionality in particular using EF